# Multiple JAX RS paths triggering the wrong method

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I have the following service (and I can't control the paths and annotations)

```
@Path("/")
public class MyService { 

 @GET
 @Path("/{id}")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public void getById(@PathParam("id") final Long id) {...}

 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public void getAll(@QueryParam("param1") Long param1
                   ,@QueryParam("param2") Long param2) {...}
}
```

**Scenario A:**

If the service is being deployed with application context of */rest/myservice* and the web.xml mapping is

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Everything works properly.
A call to GET http://localhost:8080/rest/myservice/123 invokes *getById* and a call to GET http://localhost:8080/rest/myservice?param1=123 invokes *getAll*

**Scenario B:**

If the service is being deployed with application context of */rest* and the web.xml mapping is

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/myservice/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

A call to GET http://localhost:8080/rest/myservice/123 still invokes *getById* BUT a call to GET http://localhost:8080/rest/myservice?param1=123 also invokes *getById* and Jersey crashes on NumberFormatException (It thinks that the /myservice is actually the first parameter for the method, *id* which is Long).

It's also important to mention that GET http://localhost:8080/rest/myservice/ (Note the trailing slash) does invoke *getAll* but then I'll have no way of sending the params.

The only thing I have control over is the web.xml and the application context (but it must not be */rest/myservice*. It has to be generic and unrelated to the service name)

Is there any way to get Scenario B to work?

Update: Added client code

Simple Rest call from Restlet client:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/rest/myservice/123 - 200 OK
```

`GET http://localhost:8080/rest/myservice?param1=123` result in an exception

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ExtractorException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "myservice"
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ParamConverters$AbstractStringReader.fromString(ParamConverters.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractParamValueExtractor.convert(AbstractParamValueExtractor.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractParamValueExtractor.fromString(AbstractParamValueExtractor.java:129)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.SingleValueExtractor.extract(SingleValueExtractor.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.PathParamValueFactoryProvider$PathParamValueFactory.provide(PathParamValueFactoryProvider.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:136)
```

Comment: So, if scenario B does not work for you, why can't you use scenario A?

Comment: We have lots of web services that are working with the configuration described in Scenario A. I'm trying to create some sort of a wrapper in order to load them all at once. (Why? In order to gain performance when running them in a container on a local machine with limited resources). That means I have only 1 web.xml, the wrapper's web.xml, and I can not use the configuration described in Scenario A.

Comment: Can you post the client code? It's unlikely that /myservice is interpreted as a parameter (BTW param1 is set to blah not a number).

Comment: You are correct regarding param1, edited that as well. It doesn't matter if param1 is being sent as Long or String, exception still occur.

Comment: *then I'll have no way of sending the params*: why? How about `http://localhost:8080/rest/myservice/?param1=123&param2=456`?

Comment: @shays, while not recommended, custom parameters can be sent in the HTTP header as well but before you do that, you should try to make this work the right way.

Comment: @JBNizet Yup, that solves it. What confused me is the fact that getById worked in both cases. After debugging Jersey a bit, it's clearer..the requestRelativeContext on Scenario A is / and on Scenario B is /myservice..using your solution solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, http://localhost:8080/rest/myservice/?param1=123&param2=456 does indeed work. (Thanks@[JBNizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet))

The slash before the '?' changes the *requestRelativeContext* from /myservice to /

Update: It turns out that this issue does not reproduce in newer Jersey versions. Version 2.25.1 is not affected by this.